# safety regarding a union of a pointer with a unique integer id

Tags: c++, c, pointers, associations, unions

```
typedef union {void *ptr; int id;} handle;
```

This is unsafe, correct?

I see that a unique id is based on the memory location *value* of a 64-bit pointer. The unique id then can be used to match upon or vice-versa the pointer could be used upon a matching "id".

It seems to be ok, but I'd rather ask the pro's.

(For reference) I noticed this in nuklear.h - the single header file gui library.

https://github.com/Immediate-Mode-UI/Nuklear

Comment: it is not portable, but it will work on most modern architectures except (in many cases) for example the AVR uCs which have separate address spaces for data and code. I would rather use the `uintptr_t` type to avoid not unique `id`s

Comment: Yes, this is unsafe. Mainly because the pointer and the `int` could be different sizes, e.g. 64 bits and 32 bits. So the `int` might have the same value for multiple pointers.

Comment: Please don't use both C and C++ tags. C and C++ are two very different languages, and one of the areas where they differ is unions.

Comment: where is the different tag usage ?

Answer (score 2):

The union itself is perfectly safe.

Using the union for type punning by writing to one element of the union, and then reading the other element is...not so safe.

### Types

If you want an integer that will hold a pointer, you normally want to use `uintptr_t` or `intptr_t` rather than just `int`.

### Operations

That's probably unnecessary though. At least from the sound of things, you just want some value that will let you uniquely identify an object, and be able to compare whether two references/pointers to objects really refer to the same or different objects. Assuming that's the case, you don't need to convert to an integer at all--just store the addresses in a pointer, and compare them. When comparing for [in]equality, you get meaningful results even for unrelated objects. Here's the wording from the C++ standard:

> (3.1) — If one pointer represents the address of a complete object, and another pointer represents the address one past the last element of a different complete object, the result of the comparison is unspecified.
> (3.2) — Otherwise, if the pointers are both null, both point to the same function, or both represent the same address (6.8.2), they compare equal.
> (3.3) — Otherwise, the pointers compare unequal.

So, two pointers to the same object compare equal. Two pointers to different objects compare not equal. You don't have to convert to an integer type at all to get that much (and the same is true in C).

#### Corner Case

The first clause of that (3.1) might require a little more explanation. You can create a pointer to one past the end of an array, and you can compare it to other pointers into the same array (and it's required to compare greater than any of them). There is, however, a corner case where the result isn't specified. Consider:

```cpp
int a[4];
int b;

if (a+4 == b) {
    ...
}
```

In this case, `a+4` might or might not equal `b`. It's not guaranteed either way. But keep in mind, `a+4` is a pointer you can't dereference--it isn't a pointer to an object. No pointer to any object falls into this corner case.

If you want *ordering* between the pointers, so you can compare for something like `a < b`, then things get a little dicier, and vary between C and C++. In C, about the only way to do this is (as outlined above) convert each pointer to an `intptr_t` (or `uintptr_t`) and compare those. Be careful to do each conversion once, and store the result permanently though, as the conversion isn't guaranteed to be stable.

In C++, you can use `std::less` to compare pointers for ordering, even when they're unrelated so using `a < b` directly wouldn't give meaningful results. Given some unrelated objects `a` and `b`, it doesn't guarantee what their order will be, but it does guaranteed that the results will be consistent (re-doing the same comparison will always give the same results) and transitive (so if `a<b` and `b<c`, then `a<c`).

### Summary

At least based on what you've outlined in the question, it doesn't sound like there's any reason to convert to an integer at all though. Unless you need something you haven't talked about, just store and compare the addresses, and you're good.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer - the address of the pointer is unique enough!